# Method to calculate average from ArrayList<Float> and ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java

I have a Java method which takes an

```
ArrayList<Float>
```

as a parameter. It calculates the average of the ArrayList, and returns the value.

Now I want to pass an

```
ArrayList<Integer>
```

Java will not allow this, it would be possible in C++.

So, just wondering what alternatives there are available, other than creating an identical class which differs only by the type, of the arguments passed to each method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change signature to accept:

```
List<? extends Number>
```

instead like this:

```
public Double avg(List<? extends Number> list) {
    // calculate average here
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your method should take a `List<? extends Number>` as argument, get the float value from the numbers and compute their average.

`List<? extends Number>` means: a List of some unknown type being or extending Number.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a method declaration like that:

```
public Number average(Collection<? extends Number> values)
{
...    
}
```